# How can I make subsections in a Contents list?

Tags: html, css, tableofcontents

I'm trying to make a Contents list on my article page but my validator keeps telling me `<ol>` and `<ul>` cannot be child elements of another `<ol>` or `<ul>`.

Is there any way I can enable this in the contents without my coding having errors?

My current markup is like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Contents</h2>
    <div>
        <ol>1
            <ol>1.1
            </ol>
            <ol>1.2
            </ol>
            <ol>1.1.1
            </ol>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: You really need to learn about ordered list. Your markup is invalid for sure. `ol` is used as a container. You need to have `li` inside this container for your different content. You should close every `ol`and every `li` that you use. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ol.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each *ol* element can only contain *li* tags. **If you want to nest lists** you have to use this structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Contents</h2>
    <div>
        <ol>
            <li>
                <span>1</span>      
                <ol>
                    <li>1.1</li>
                    <li>1.2</li>
                    <li>
                        <ol>
                            <li>1.2.1</li>
                            <li>1.2.2</li>
                        </ol>
                    </li>
                    <li>1.3</li>
                </ol>
            <li>
            <li>
                <span>2</span>      
                <ol>
                    <li>2.1</li>
                    <li>2.2</li>
                    <li>2.3</li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, its looking better now. Only problem is there is numbers for items under <span>1</span> but none for the categories under <span>2</span>. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Just repeat the structure... The rule is always li 's inside ol. But inside a li you can put whatever you want, as it behaves like a div. Anyway, if your are using an ol you should get the numbers automatically, don't you?

Comment: Yes I copied the steps and my numbers are appearing automatically, however Items 1., 5. and 6. are followed by blanks whereas 2., 3., 4., 1.1, and 1.2, (in the first subsection), and 1.1.1 (in the second subsection) have titles. Also my validator is giving me errors for unclosed elements

Comment: What's CodePen and Fiddle?

Comment: This http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQzbKL is my code in an online editor called CodePen, you can test there, save the changes and post the link to the new version...

Answer (score 0):

Your `<ol>` just declares the start of a new ordered list, so anything inside of your list, you want to place in a list item, `<li>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Contents</h2>
  <div>
    <ol>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>1.1</li>
      <li>1.2</li>
      <li>1.1.1</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, you can use `<ul>` in place of `<ol>` to get a bulleted list instead of numbered.